# How to check moving averages on one time framer greater than the current time frame

Tags: pine-script

I want to check moving averages on one time frame greater than the current chart time frame in pine script
For example if chart is  on m15 I want to check moving averages on m30  if chart is on h1 it check on h2 and so on
Somehow it get current chart time frame automatically and plot ma for 1 time frame greater

Answer (score 0):

The [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function is what you are looking for.

```
//@version=4
study(title="High Time Frame MA", overlay=true)
src = close, len = 9
out = sma(src, len)
out1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, '30', out)
plot(out1)
```

## Edit

There is no next upper timeframe. Timeframe can be anything. What Tradingview lists are some convenient values.

You can get the current timeframe in minutes, and request data from `2 * current timeframe` for example.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="High Time Frame MA", overlay=true)

f_resInMinutes() => 
    _resInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)

curr_tf_in_min = f_resInMinutes()
tf_2 = str.tostring(2 * curr_tf_in_min)
src = close, len = 9
out = ta.sma(src, len)
out1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf_2, out)
plot(out1)
```

Comment: Tnx dude but this is not what I want .I want it get my current chart time frame and plot ma for next upper time frame

Comment: Please see my edit.